# I am unable to produce map images with d3 and cannot figure out why D3 is working for some files but not others

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I apologize, this may be the dumbest question I could possible ask, and i just need a direction to go to fix this. I downloaded a tutorial from github, and I cannot get this to work, it works for one of the tutorials but not the others. I tried downloading D3 tutorials from the D3 page itself and virtually none of them work, they just produce blank pages.
I have tried checking my browser settings, i have tried uninstalling java and re-installing it.

This for example Does not work, it produces the rest of the page but not the map, which is what i need

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>D3: Choropleth</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">



        body {
            background-color: gray;
        }

        svg {
            background-color: black;
        }



    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">



        //Year of CO2 data to map
        var year = "2010";

        //Width and height
        var w = 500;
        var h = 300;

        //Define map projection
        var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
                               .center([ 0, 40 ])
                               .translate([ w/2, h/2 ])
                               .scale([ w/7 ]);

        //Define path generator
        var path = d3.geo.path()
                         .projection(projection);

        //Define quantize scale to sort data values into buckets of color
        //Colors by Cynthia Brewer (colorbrewer2.org), YlOrRd
        var color = d3.scale.quantize()
                            .range([ "#ffffb2", "#fecc5c", "#fd8d3c", "#f03b20", "#bd0026" ]);

        //Create SVG
        var svg = d3.select("body")
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("width", w)
                    .attr("height", h);

        //Load in CO2 data
        d3.csv("data/co2/co2_emissions.csv", function(data) {

            //Set input domain for color scale
            color.domain([
                d3.min(data, function(d) { return +d[year]; }), 
                d3.max(data, function(d) { return +d[year]; })
            ]);

            //Load in GeoJSON data
            d3.json("data/geo/mapshaper_output.json", function(json) {
                
                //Merge the CO2 data and GeoJSON into a single array
                //
                //Loop through once for each CO2 data value
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            
                    //Grab country name
                    var dataCountryCode = data[i].countryCode;
                    
                    //Grab data value, and convert from string to float
                    var dataValue = +data[i][year];
            
                    //Find the corresponding country inside the GeoJSON
                    for (var j = 0; j < json.features.length; j++) {
                    
                        //We'll check the official ISO country code
                        var jsonCountryCode = json.features[j].properties.iso_a3;
            
                        if (dataCountryCode == jsonCountryCode) {
                    
                            //Copy the data value into the GeoJSON
                            json.features[j].properties.co2 = dataValue;
                            
                            //Stop looking through the JSON
                            break;
                            
                        }
                    }       
                }

                //Bind data and create one path per GeoJSON feature
                svg.selectAll("path")
                   .data(json.features)
                   .enter()
                   .append("path")
                   .attr("d", path)
                   .style("fill", function(d) {

                        //Get data value
                        var value = d.properties.co2;

                        if (value) {
                            //If value exists…
                            return color(value);
                        } else {
                            //If value is undefined…
                            return "#ccc";
                        }

                    });
        
            });  //End d3.json()

        });  //End d3.csv()


    
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This one however does work as intended, and i cannot figure out the difference

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>D3: Stack layout, stacked bar chart, but flipped</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">



        body {
            background-color: gray;
        }

        svg {
            background-color: white;
        }



    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">



        //Width and height
        var w = 500;
        var h = 300;

        //Original data
        var dataset = [
            [
                { x: 0, y: 5 },
                { x: 1, y: 4 },
                { x: 2, y: 2 },
                { x: 3, y: 7 },
                { x: 4, y: 23 }
            ],
            [
                { x: 0, y: 10 },
                { x: 1, y: 12 },
                { x: 2, y: 19 },
                { x: 3, y: 23 },
                { x: 4, y: 17 }
            ],
            [
                { x: 0, y: 22 },
                { x: 1, y: 28 },
                { x: 2, y: 32 },
                { x: 3, y: 35 },
                { x: 4, y: 43 }
            ]
        ];

        //Set up stack method
        var stack = d3.layout.stack()
                        .order("reverse");  //Flip the order

        //Data, stacked
        stack(dataset);

        //Set up scales
        var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .domain(d3.range(dataset[0].length))
            .rangeRoundBands([0, w], 0.05);
    
        var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0,             
                d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
                    return d3.max(d, function(d) {
                        return d.y0 + d.y;
                    });
                })
            ])
            .range([0, h]);
            
        //Easy colors accessible via a 10-step ordinal scale
        var colors = d3.scale.category10();
    
        //Create SVG element
        var svg = d3.select("body")
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("width", w)
                    .attr("height", h);

        // Add a group for each row of data
        var groups = svg.selectAll("g")
            .data(dataset)
            .enter()
            .append("g")
            .style("fill", function(d, i) {
                return colors(i);
            });

        // Add a rect for each data value
        var rects = groups.selectAll("rect")
            .data(function(d) { return d; })
            .enter()
            .append("rect")
            .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                return xScale(i);
            })
            .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
            .attr("y", function(d) {
                return h - yScale(d.y0) - yScale(d.y);  //Flip the math!
            })
            .attr("height", function(d) {
                return yScale(d.y);
            });
            


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you running the examples on a server or as local files?

Comment: Local, i've never worked with HTML and internet functions like this before, how would i run them on a server?

Comment: You won't be able to use d3.csv or d3.json etc due to browser security restrictions when loading a file without a server. There's lots of options to set up a testing/local server on your computer, but which one you might want depends on a few factors, there are lots of options and loads of how-to's. On my windows machine, I generally use [WampServer](https://www.instructables.com/Setting-up-a-local-webserver-on-your-computer/) for simple testing, but, there are lots of options out there.